# Instagram get next_max_tag_id

Tags: python, api, celery, instagram

I'm trying to do some analytics analysis on Instagram photos that are posted with a specified hashtag. So now I'm trying to store all the images in a temporary database that'll be used for the analysis.

I'm using python and I've a celery task to get all the images, but it is not working when I run with a next_max_tag_id, which is probably wrong.

Does someone know how to get the correct next_max_tag_id?

this is the code I'm using:

```py
@task()
def get_latest_photos():
    next_max_tag_id = get_option('next_max_tag_id')

    if not next_max_tag_id:
        next_max_tag_id = 0

    url = BASE + '/tags/{tag}/media/recent?client_id={cliend_id}' \
        '&max_tag_id={max_id}'.format(**{
            'tag': a_tag,
            'cliend_id': getattr(settings, 'INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID'),
            'max_id': next_max_tag_id
        })

    while url:
        request = requests.get(url)

        if request.status_code != 200:
            pass #TODO: error

        json_response = request.json()

        if json_response['meta']['code'] != 200:
            pass #TODO: error

        # do something with json_response['data']:

        url = None
        if json_response.has_key('pagination'):
            pagination = json_response['pagination']

            if pagination.has_key('next_url'):
                url = json_response['pagination']['next_url']

            if pagination.has_key('next_max_tag_id'):
                next_max_tag_id = pagination['next_max_tag_id']

    update_option('next_max_tag_id', next_max_tag_id)
```

The flow is basically this:

1. get next_max_tag_id from the db (defaults to 0)
2. while we have a valid URL it fetches the data, the next url and the next_max_tag_id
3. updates the next_max_tag_id

The only thing that seems wrong to me is the next_max_tag_id, because every time I go to the API URL with the last next_max_tag_id I get the old images.

Comment: i am experimenting myself right now, as far as i saw it next_max is going in the history directory while next_min goes to the future

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here's how to use pagination correctly. You have to loop through the pages and reference the function you're in. You can update the script below that gets everyone you're following and query for next_max_id as well.

```
currently_following = set([])
def parse_following(next_url=None):
    if next_url == None:
        urlUserMedia = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=%s" % (auth_token)
    else:
        urlUserMedia = next_url
    values = {
              'client_id' : client_id}
    try:
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        req = urllib2.Request(urlUserMedia,None,headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        result = response.read()
        dataObj = json.loads(result)
        next_url = None
        if dataObj.get('pagination') is not None:
            next_url = dataObj.get('pagination').get('next_url')
            currently_following.update(user['id'] for user in dataObj['data'])
        if next_url is not None:
            parse_following(next_url)

    except Exception as e:
        print e
```